# Finding the 1000th prime number (python) debug

Tags: python, primes

I am attempting to write a code to calculate the 1000th prime number and I'm running into an issue with my loop counter that i don't understand.

```
prime_test = 1
count=0
for count in range(0,1001):
    for divisor in range(2,prime_test):
        if (prime_test % divisor) == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(prime_test)
        count += 1
    prime_test+=1
```

Could someone please explain why the above code is dysfunctional? The problem is that the count variable iterates at the same rate as the prime_test variable. How do I separate the two such that count only increases when a new prime is found and not when the loop is engaged?

Comment: You're using the same variable `count` for `for count in range(0, 1001):`. So `count += 1` has no effect.

Comment: I encourage you to avoid `for-else` and `while-else`. Most readers are not familiar.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `for count in range(0, 1001):`. That just increments count sequentially, not when it finds a prime. Use a `while` loop.

```
prime_test = 2
count = 0
while count < 1000:
    for divisor in range(2,prime_test):
        if (prime_test % divisor) == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(prime_test)
        count += 1
    prime_test += 1
```

You also should start `prime_test` at `2`, not `1`, since `1` isn't a prime number, but your algorithm will say it is.

Comment: what's the functional difference between the while and for loop that causes this? I can see that the while loop works but i dont see why for wouldn't work the same way. I see that it counts sequentially but i dont know why. Is the count in the for loop just increasing with each loop instead of when it hits the count +=1 line?

Comment: You only want to increment `count` when you find a prime. But `range(0, 1001)` increments every time.

Comment: Nice solution! It is the 1st time I see an `else` assotiated to `for`-loop. Could you tell me the name of this syntactical "property" or reference to the doc?

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). I think this feature is unique to Python.

Answer (score 0):

One more answer as the same thing might need to be repeated thousand times before it could be understood.

**Setting the value of `c` before the loop has no effect at all and the new to `c` within the loop assigned value will be overwritten by next loop loop as `c` will be set to the next value provided by `range()`.** Python `for c in range()` loops are not like loops in some other programming languages. So every newbie has to go through this ... wondering how it comes.

Following code demonstrates this:

```
c = 100
for c in range(5):
    print(c, end=' -> ')
    c = c + 5
    print(c)
```

printing

```
0 -> 5
1 -> 6
2 -> 7
3 -> 8
4 -> 9
```

---

---

If you change your code to:

```
prime_test = 2
counter=0
for count in range(0,11):
    for divisor in range(2, prime_test):
        if (prime_test % divisor) == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(prime_test)
        counter += 1
    prime_test+=1
print(f'{counter=} , {prime_test=} ')
```

you will get as output:

```
2
3
5
7
11
counter=5 , prime_test=13
```